# How to add a column to a table with populated data? [POSTGRES]

Tags: postgresql

I was googling this question, but couldn't find anything that works.

I'm to tying to add a column to a table in postgres and then to populate the new column with data for the entire column (see example below)

original table `orders`:

```
order_id|order_date|order_time
--------+----------+----------
       1|2015-01-01|  11:38:36
       2|2015-01-01|  11:57:40
       3|2015-01-01|  12:12:28
       4|2015-01-01|  12:16:31
       5|2015-01-01|  12:21:30
       6|2015-01-01|  12:29:36
       7|2015-01-01|  12:50:37
       8|2015-01-01|  12:51:37
       9|2015-01-01|  12:52:01
      10|2015-01-01|  13:00:15
```

Say, I would like to make a column which is a timestamp by combining `full_date`.

this calls for: `ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN full_date timestamp;`

Now, I would like to alter the original table by adding the data for the `full_date` column, so it would look like this:

```
order_id|order_date|order_time|full_date              |
--------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
       1|2015-01-01|  11:38:36|2015-01-01 11:38:36.000|
       2|2015-01-01|  11:57:40|2015-01-01 11:57:40.000|
       3|2015-01-01|  12:12:28|2015-01-01 12:12:28.000|
       4|2015-01-01|  12:16:31|2015-01-01 12:16:31.000|
       5|2015-01-01|  12:21:30|2015-01-01 12:21:30.000|
       6|2015-01-01|  12:29:36|2015-01-01 12:29:36.000|
       7|2015-01-01|  12:50:37|2015-01-01 12:50:37.000|
       8|2015-01-01|  12:51:37|2015-01-01 12:51:37.000|
       9|2015-01-01|  12:52:01|2015-01-01 12:52:01.000|
      10|2015-01-01|  13:00:15|2015-01-01 13:00:15.000|
```

The only solution I managed to find, is by creating a new table from the `orders` table and then dropping the original table.

I tried `INSERT INTO orders(full_date) SELECT order_date + order_time FROM orders`
but it didn't work.

My question is, how do I populate the `full_date` data into the newly created column directly into the original `orders` table without creating a new table and then dropping the original.

Thank you in advance for any input!

Comment: Please provide the structure of "orders" table. Normally date + time works.

Comment: @SahapAsci, Thanks for the input. What do you mean by the structure of the 'orders' table?
id = primary key
order_date = date 
order_time = time
full_date = timestamp

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Have you concidered adding a GENERATED ALWAYS colum?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini, Thanks for the input Lennart. I wasn't aware of GENERATED ALWAYS. However after looking at the docs, I noticed, this only applies during the creation of the table itself. 

I managed to solve this issue by using Update Join.

Comment: @Sagireichen: no, you can add a generated column later as well. And it would automatically be populated with the result of the expression.

Comment: @Sagireichen no, you can add a generated column: https://dbfiddle.uk/D7CJANqo

Comment: @Lennart you can add that as an answer

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, thanks! the fiddle was very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a generated column:

```
alter table orders
    add column ts timestamp
        generated always as (dt + tm) stored;
```

Additional things to concider:

- Don't add a column at all. It does not add anything that cannot be expressed today (beside precision perhaps)
- Replace the current columns.
- 

```
alter table orders
    alter column ts drop expression;
alter table orders
    drop column dt;
alter table orders
    drop column tm;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dmSBMg0k)

Answer (score 1):

Its trivial

```
UPDATE orders SET full_date = order_date+ order_time
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by using Update Join:

Just in case anyone in the future would be interested, this did the trick:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE orders ADD COLUMN full_date TIMESTAMP;

UPDATE orders o1
SET full_date = o2.order_date + o1.order_time
FROM orders o2
WHERE o1.order_id = o2.order_id;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why is a join necessary?

Comment: You dont need the join. Also, concider adding not null after update